# Solving r in a constant annuity equation

Tags: equation-solving

How can I calculate `r` in the following constant annuity equation:

```
330,000 = 1,536.96/r * (1 - 1/(1+r)^25)
r = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSolve`,

```
Eq = 330000 == 1536.96/r*(1 - 1/(1 + r)^25)

NSolve[Eq, r]
```

or use `FindRoot`.